# Vue.js dynamic two way data binding between parent and child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use a combination of v-for and v-model to get a two-way data bind for some input forms. I want to dynamically create child components. Currently, I don't see the child component update the parent's data object.

My template looks like this

```
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="row">
    Parent Val
    {{ ranges }}
  </div>

   <div class="row">
     <button 
        v-on:click="addRange"
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Add time-range
     </button>
    </div>

  <time-range 
    v-for="range in ranges"
    :box-index="$index"
    v-bind:data.sync="range">
  </time-range>

</div>

<template id="time-range">
  <div class="row">
    <input v-model="data" type="text">
  </div>
</template>
```

and the js this

```
Vue.component('time-range', {
  template: '#time-range',
  props: ['data'],
  data: {}
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ranges: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addRange: function () {
        this.ranges.push('')
    },
  }
})
```

I've also made a js fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/8mdso9fj/96/

Comment: you can emit custom events to send data from child to parent in vue2. have you tried that ?

Comment: In particular, you are trying to use the `.sync` modifier. You should read the documentation for [how that works](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier).

Comment: Hi guys. I did try the .sync modifier but didn't have any luck with it https://jsfiddle.net/8mdso9fj/97/

Comment: `v-model` on a prop is not going to work. You need to set it up to emit an `update:data` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: the use of an array complicates things: you cannot modify an alias (the v-for variable).

One approach that isn't mentioned often is to [catch the native input event as it bubbles up to the component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components). This can be a little simpler than having to propagate Vue events up the chain, as long as you know there's an element issuing a native `input` or `change` event somewhere in your component. I'm using `change` for this example, so you won't see it happen until you leave the field. Due to the array issue, I have to use `splice` to have Vue notice the change to an element.

```js
Vue.component('time-range', {
  template: '#time-range',
  props: ['data']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ranges: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addRange: function () {
        this.ranges.push('')
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="row">
    Parent Val
    {{ ranges }}
  </div>
  
   <div class="row">
     <button 
        v-on:click="addRange"
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Add time-range
     </button>
    </div>

  <time-range 
    v-for="range, index in ranges"
    :data="range"
    :key="index"
    @change.native="(event) => ranges.splice(index, 1, event.target.value)">
  </time-range>
</div>

<template id="time-range">
  <div class="row">
    <input :value="data" type="text">
  </div>
</template>
```

To use [the `.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier), the child component has to emit an `update:`*variablename* event that the parent will catch and do its magic. In this case, *variablename* is `data`. You still have to use the array-subscripting notation, because you still can't modify a v-for alias variable, but Vue is smart about `.sync` on the array element, so there's no messy `splice`.

```js
Vue.component('time-range', {
  template: '#time-range',
  props: ['data'],
  methods: {
    emitUpdate(event) {
      this.$emit('update:data', event.target.value);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ranges: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addRange: function () {
        this.ranges.push('')
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="row">
    Parent Val
    {{ ranges }}
  </div>
  
   <div class="row">
     <button 
        v-on:click="addRange"
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Add time-range
     </button>
    </div>

  <time-range 
    v-for="range, index in ranges"
    :data.sync="ranges[index]"
    :key="index">
  </time-range>

</div>

<template id="time-range">
  <div class="row">
    <input :value="data" type="text" @change="emitUpdate">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks @RoyJ ! That did it for the input fields. I had some other custom fields I ran into some issues with but I got around it by using watch and emitting events similar to the regular text inputs